# Configure Activiti to reuse the existing user/group data in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, activiti

I am using Spring Boot 1.4.3.RELEASE. I have already created a simple MVC application to manage users and groups.
Now, I am trying to integrate Activiti 5.21.0 within my project, and **REUSE** the existing user/group tables by Activiti.

I have extended the default **`UserEntityManager`** and **`GroupEntityManager`** classes from Activiti like below:

**CustomUserEntityManager.java**

```
import java.util.List;

import org.activiti.engine.impl.Page;
import org.activiti.engine.impl.UserQueryImpl;
import org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.IdentityInfoEntity;
import org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.UserEntity;
import org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.UserEntityManager;

import com.example.spring.dao.UserDao;
import com.example.spring.model.User;

public class CustomUserEntityManager extends UserEntityManager {

    private UserDao userDao;

    public CustomUserEntityManager(UserDao userDao) {
        this.userDao = userDao;
    }

    @Override
    public UserEntity findUserById(String userId) {
        User user = userDao.findById(Integer.parseInt(userId));
        return userToActivitiUser(user);
    }

    @Override
    public org.activiti.engine.identity.User createNewUser(String userId) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public void insertUser(org.activiti.engine.identity.User user) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public void updateUser(org.activiti.engine.identity.User updatedUser) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteUser(String userId) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public List<org.activiti.engine.identity.User> findUserByQueryCriteria(UserQueryImpl query, Page page) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public long findUserCountByQueryCriteria(UserQueryImpl query) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public IdentityInfoEntity findUserInfoByUserIdAndKey(String userId, String key) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> findUserInfoKeysByUserIdAndType(String userId, String type) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    private UserEntity userToActivitiUser(User user) {
        UserEntity activitiUser = new UserEntity();
        activitiUser.setId(user.getId().toString());
        activitiUser.setPassword(user.getPassword());
        activitiUser.setFirstName(user.getUsername());
        activitiUser.setLastName(user.getLastName());
        activitiUser.setEmail(user.getEmail());
        return activitiUser;
    }

}
```

**ActivitiGroupEntityManager.java**

```
import java.util.List;

import org.activiti.engine.identity.Group;
import org.activiti.engine.identity.GroupQuery;
import org.activiti.engine.impl.GroupQueryImpl;
import org.activiti.engine.impl.Page;
import org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.GroupEntityManager;

import com.example.spring.dao.CMSGroupDao;

public class CustomGroupEntityManager extends GroupEntityManager {

    private CMSGroupDao groupDao;

    public CustomGroupEntityManager(CMSGroupDao groupDao) {
        this.groupDao = groupDao;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Group> findGroupsByUser(String userId) {
        // TODO add logic
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Group createNewGroup(String groupId) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteGroup(String groupId) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public GroupQuery createNewGroupQuery() {
            return super.createNewGroupQuery();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Group> findGroupByQueryCriteria(GroupQueryImpl query, Page page) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public long findGroupCountByQueryCriteria(GroupQueryImpl query) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

}
```

then, I added my custom factories like below:

**CustomUserManagerFactory.java**

```
import org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.Session;
import org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.example.spring.dao.UserDao;

@Component(value = "customUserManagerFactory")
public class CustomUserManagerFactory implements SessionFactory {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Override
    public Class<?> getSessionType() {
        return CustomUserEntityManager.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Session openSession() {
        return new CustomUserEntityManager(userDao);
    }

}
```

**CustomGroupManagerFactory.java**

```
import org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.Session;
import org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.example.spring.dao.CMSGroupDao;

@Component(value = "customGroupManagerFactory")
public class CustomGroupManagerFactory implements SessionFactory {

    @Autowired
    private CMSGroupDao groupDao;

    @Override
    public Class<?> getSessionType() {
        return CustomGroupEntityManager.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Session openSession() {
        return new CustomGroupEntityManager(groupDao);
    }

}
```

Finally, I added my ProcessEngine configuration bean like below:

**ProcessEngineConfig.java**

```
package com.example.spring.configuration;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

import org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.SessionFactory;
import org.activiti.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration;
import org.activiti.spring.boot.ProcessEngineConfigurationConfigurer;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigureBefore;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@AutoConfigureBefore(org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration.class)
public class ProcessEngineConfig implements ProcessEngineConfigurationConfigurer{

    @Resource(name = "customUserManagerFactory")
    private SessionFactory userManagerFactory;

    @Resource(name = "customGroupManagerFactory")
    private SessionFactory groupManagerFactory;

    public void configure(SpringProcessEngineConfiguration pec) {
        pec.setDbIdentityUsed(false); 
        List<SessionFactory> customSessionFactories = new ArrayList<SessionFactory>();
        customSessionFactories.add(userManagerFactory);
        customSessionFactories.add(groupManagerFactory);
        if (pec.getCustomSessionFactories() == null){
            pec.setCustomSessionFactories(customSessionFactories);
        }
        else{
            pec.getCustomSessionFactories().addAll(customSessionFactories);
        }
    }
}
```

Important parts from **pom.xml**

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <activiti.version>5.21.0</activiti.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Activiti Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
            <artifactId>activiti-spring-boot-starter-basic</artifactId>
            <version>${activiti.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
            <artifactId>activiti-spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>${activiti.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring-boot Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        .......
        .......
     </dependencies>
```

The application is executing without any runtime error, **HOWEVER**, when I create a user using `org.activiti.engine.IdentityService.newUser()` the user is created and saved in Activit user table and `UnsupportedOperationException()` is not thrown which mean that the custom configuration is not working.

Any help will be appreciated!!

Comment: Hi @Andromida, I'm working on something similar and I'm a bit lost as I'm new to spring boot and activiti. Could you provide maybe a github link or something to this so that we could learn how the entire thing works? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Andromida. I am having similar use case to work upon would appreciate if you can share sample code with us.

Comment: Hi @Gautam, all what you need is described in the question, just align with the updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the CustomGroupManagerFactory the type should be :

```
  @Override
  public Class<?> getSessionType() {
      return GroupIdentityManager.class;
  }
```

For CustomUserManagerFactory the type should be :

```
  @Override
  public Class<?> getSessionType() {
      return UserIdentityManager.class;
  }
```

I hope the solution above helps you to get it working.

Comment: Hello Ahmed, Actually, only fixing the type in the custom factories resolved the issue. +1 for the hint and please edit the answer and keep the first two steps only to accept it

Comment: Hello Andromida, I am glad to hear that the issue is resolved. I edited my answer and thank you.