# Activiti 6.0 to custom user/group data in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, activiti

In activiti 6.0, I have two app: activiti-app and activiti-rest
I want activiti-app and activiti-rest use my custom authentication (own user and group database).

I have follow this question to make a custom authentication session

[Configure Activiti to reuse the existing user/group data in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41611271/configure-activiti-to-reuse-the-existing-user-group-data-in-spring-boot)

But, after create project, I don't know what should I do next?

I have try to copy .jar code to activiti-app/WEB-INF/lib and activiti-rest/WEB-INF/lib but nothing happend.

So, what should I do after I done my custom authentication project to customize activiti 6.0 user and group.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you configure your custom user and group session factories are registered with the Process Engine Configuration.
There are a couple of ways to do this.

1. The easiest is to simply update the application engine configuration classes and set the session factories.
2. If you prefer not to touch the core code (this is more of an issue if using th enterprise edition) or you re using Spring Boot, you can implement an "processEngineConfigurationConfigurer" class which allows you to get access to the Process Engine Configuration before it is initialized.

   Which ever way you choose, the registration code is the same:

   ```
   Map<Class<?>, SessionFactory> sessionFactories = processEngineConfiguration.getSessionFactories();
   sessionFactories.put(userManagerFactory.getSessionType(), userManagerFactory);
   sessionFactories.put(groupManagerFactory.getSessionType(), groupManagerFactory);

   processEngineConfiguration.setSessionFactories(sessionFactories);
   ```

This should register your custom session factories.
Hope this helps,
Greg